# Regex to match strings in between similar delimiters

Tags: regex

I have a long  string

Blah Blah Blah
*****Some text 1 blah*****
More Blah...
*****Some text 2 blah*****
blah bleh...

I want to extract the strings in between "**" so I would get

> Some text 1 blah
>
> Some text 2 blah

I tried using:

```
var expression = @"(?<=**)(.*?)(?=**)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(theLargeString, expression);
```

but it is throwing an error:

```
parsing "(?<=**)(.*?)(?=**)" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.
```

I am new to Regex... Any advices?

Comment: please add the relevant language tag to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape the *s...

```
\*\*(.*?)\*\*
```

regexp sample 1
[image]

Comment: since your data looks pretty well delimited, I think this answer which avoids the "lookarounds" is simpler and faster, and so is preferred.